# Convert datetime 64ns to mm/dd/yyyy in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime, date-conversion

I have a date column of format `datetime64[ns]`

```
date
01/04/2020
01/06/2020
01/08/2020
```

the first row represents apr-2020, then second row is june-2020  and third is aug-2020

From my actual data ,the date is stored as "dd/mm/yyyy" in the date column and in the pandas column is shown as "yyyy-mm-dd". I think it's just the represenation

I am trying to convert the date column to "mm/dd/yyyy" and I am using the below code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

While I export the data again, the date format for the date "04/01/2020" is represented as Jan-2020 instead of Apr-2020. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think your solution is OK, but is possible input data are `mm/dd` instead `dd/mm` ?

Comment: nope. the input data is in dd/mm only.. and that' where I am getting confused as to why the date column is not getting converted.

Comment: hmmm, weird. Is possible add data sample for see this problem?

Comment: added the data for your reference

Comment: Ok, but here is problem, if column is `datetime64[ns]` then not possible format `01/04/2020`

Comment: Also this data returned wrong ouput? for me working well.

Comment: but it is actually like that only.. my date contains the same values and it is of the format datetime64[ns]

Comment: if you export the data into an excel and look from the filter you will see that all the values belongs to the january month.

Comment: Then problem is excel parsing it wrongly.

Comment: Could be. then how can I rectify it?

Comment: I think problem is in excel side, pandas working here perfeclty fine.

Comment: how do I rectify it then? any option to parse correctly the dates while importing the data?

Comment: I not working with excle so not idea how prevent it.